# "System BootOrder not found" when trying to boot into Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot

Everything was okay. I booted into windows 10 and everything was fine, then I restarted (clicking Restart) but this happened: https://youtu.be/T1ZFraY1rqY

The message

```
System BootOrder not found.  Initializing defaults.


Reset System
```

flashes briefly on the screen before the system reboot.  This repeats.

Comment: btw, I am dual-booting ubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Could I bother you to edit your post to make the title say something meaningful about the error you encountered? Also, a few words of description in the body would be help future searches find a similar problem (or even an existing Q&A!). Thank you!

Comment: Related (possibly a dupe): [Messed up boot - System BootOrder not found](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/443508)

Comment: Also see [Unable to install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire ES1-533](https://askubuntu.com/a/876153/473234) over on https://AskUbuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I've been fixed this. I spammed <kbd>F10</kbd> when it started, then I went to boot options and set Windows boot manager.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with my MSI GE63.  I was able to successfully load grub after disabling both secure boot and security device support options under BIOS settings.